# appending item into a listmodel which is in another file

Tags: listview, qml

My question is how can you append item coming from another `listmodel.qml` to another `ListModel` that is in another qml file. 
There is a button in `ItemDelegate` from the `NameDeleget.qml`. when I click that button I want to append the name to the `ListModel` in `favorite.qml`.
When I push that `favorite.qml` into a `StackView` I want it to show the appended item.
Anyone with idea how to do that.

**Home.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12

ApplicationWIndow {
    id: root
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    
    ListView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: NameModel{}
        delegate: NameDeleget{}
    }
}
```

**NameModel.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.0

ListModel {
    listElement {name:""; value:}
    listElement {name:""; value:}
    listElement {name:""; value:}
}
```

**NameDeleget.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12

ItemDelegate {
    width: parent.width
    text: model.name
    RoundButton {
        id: btn
        anchos.right: parent.right
        onclicked: {
        // When the button is clciked I want to append the clciked name to the "favorite.qml"
    }
}
```

**Favorite.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
import Qt.labs.settings 1.1
import Qt.labs.settings 1.0

Item {
    ListView {
        id: listView
        anchors.fill: parent

        model: ListModel {
            id: dataModel
            ListElement {name: "test1"; value: 1}
        }

        delegate: ItemDelegate {
            id: itemDelegete
            width: parent.width
            text: name +":"+ value
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Favorite.qml` and `Home.qml` have no reference to each other. use a singleton item or connect them in some other way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I interpret your requirements as:

- On HomePage.qml view ListModel containing names and pick your favourites
- On FavouritePage.qml view the same ListModel but only show the selected favourites
- Navigate between the two pages using StackView

So, to do this:

- I ignored the requirement of two ListModel since only one ListModel is needed
- Declare the ListModel in a parent scope so both pages can see it
- Use DelegateModel on the second page to filter the records

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.15

Page {
    property var fav: ([])
    StackView {
        id: stackView
        anchors.fill: parent
        initialItem: "HomePage.qml"
    }
    ListModel {
        id: nameModel
        ListElement { name: "Steve Jobs" }
        ListElement { name: "Bill Gates" }
        ListElement { name: "Jeff Bezos" }
    }
}

//HomePage.qml
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.15
Page {
    header: Frame {
        background: Rectangle { color: "lightgrey" }
        Text {
            text: "HomePage.qml (%1 total)".arg(nameModel.count)
        }
    }
    ColumnLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent
        ListView {
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            model: nameModel
            delegate: Frame {
                background: Rectangle {
                    color: (index & 1) ? "#f0f0f0" : "#e0e0e0"
                }
                width: ListView.view.width
                RowLayout {
                    width: parent.width
                    CheckBox {
                        checked: fav.indexOf(model.index) !== -1
                        onToggled: {
                            let obj = fav;
                            let idx = obj.indexOf(model.index);
                            if (idx === -1) {
                                obj.push(model.index);
                            } else {
                                obj = obj.filter(e => e !== model.index);
                            }
                            fav = obj;
                        }
                    }
                    Text {
                        Layout.fillWidth: true
                        text: model.name
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Text {
            text: JSON.stringify(fav)
        }
    }
    footer: Button {
        text: "Goto Favourites"
        onClicked: stackView.push("FavouritePage.qml")
    }
}

//FavouritePage.qml
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.15
import QtQml.Models 2.15
Page {
    header: Frame {
        background: Rectangle { color: "lightgrey" }
        Text {
            text: "FavouritePage.qml (%1 total)".arg(favourites.count)
        }
    }
    ListView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: FilterDelegateModel {
            id: favourites
            model: nameModel
            filter: model => fav.indexOf(model.index) !== -1
            delegate: Frame {
                background: Rectangle {
                    color: (index & 1) ? "#f0f0f0" : "#e0e0e0"
                }
                width: ListView.view.width
                RowLayout {
                    width: parent.width
                    Text {
                        Layout.fillWidth: true
                        text: model.name
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    footer: Button {
        text: "Back to HomePage"
        onClicked: stackView.pop()
    }
}

//FilterDelegateModel.qml
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQml.Models 2.15

DelegateModel {
    property var filter: null
    groups: [
        DelegateModelGroup {
            id: allItems
            name: "all"
            includeByDefault: true
            onCountChanged: Qt.callLater(update)
        },
        DelegateModelGroup {
            id: visibleItems
            name: "visible"
        }
    ]
    filterOnGroup: "visible"
    function update() {
        allItems.setGroups(0, allItems.count, [ "all" ] );
        for (let index = 0; index < allItems.count; index++) {
            let item = allItems.get(index).model;
            let visible = !filter || filter(item);
            if (!visible) continue;
            allItems.setGroups(index, 1, [ "all", "visible" ]);
        }
    }
    Component.onCompleted: Qt.callLater(update)
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=AAAPVHic7Vfdb9s2EH%2F3X3FRsUFCPTUu0Bdn7gC7S7oga5am2B6CPCjySeZCkZ5EOXFb%2F%2B87UoysT9vBigEDRgO2dd%2F34%2FGOYslSpgqu1FXOwnt47Y%2FeDFiN5s%2BkUKnkWSfzIljLXGUw0rzBb0GM8GUAtJapXGKq1rAKUoiC1Rjcm1vPsK5VEN7%2FzvDBiurF5mPInuglNRDhQqaZHzHOx7AMUhRqqyKYYgH%2FRWEyBue9TFC79%2F9KuGNkNub7gmXqVzlH3nAmggQNvaRqyZ85JuQDvhg%2Bmb1WuEI4l3eZYw32ik4pSDgLFO4XPccogil%2BlqXoZrAZDF69qmbRgPof7k1laxYYzDEdw2lK0VRguSP441TmguD5iKEKRMyJD6HkksQdzuKFilNcV%2FP7hI%2BqYkMvRaTGjoD73QiUVAH3HD9IY7eE3w%2FJofJKA5vK3s0kzxNRpFHxsbMqNN6N2jJkY8So%2FMHmajEGlebYJ%2FIedaodMokOuat49KJnjGn%2F28juQbglp5dF3WVijo%2FwPYw8%2BAmcF9Gx%2FjhAAL%2FAY%2F1xWuqbFuWhyPkJHH%2BlvwyxJfpRPrQQ7zBVwN5jQ6%2FZAsP7qXzsMWNS1CJIWFB%2F8E2el5FrIC6ePDiaTOCHUa8BKT7JmCAkE%2F1e9OKoQN79CRPt6mSvKJs%2FkigpdEa1W59FtGda34Tu7QnMZEF%2Blnm2eIaTDSDP%2BiqnYdtmQnWtMHURJm8BDbDPcLeTS5AWPvqNdBvopnZ0lOo64CRXV9GMilT1sT0wkDpl%2B3RA4zu%2FvvzgZyplImbR2iV0urtbJKXSbXiaKyVFxZTtn2dSSTgNVjJPmR4qJV%2BKGWfFwSlHZlFATilejkKvOl5a7G87Y7a8hPumP1qlf3%2F4tDJtTaCoRHbXCOoYJzvHjx0Qp%2BawvbMDoXn%2F0IsVbc%2BGcPiQKY6xrWh9lp%2FTO%2F%2BfUNX1H2g0h3WKKW0a1TY83bj2tQq5dOttoV2tBzSHxhkfdFV7%2FS3Alq7IeVHTutCW2RhuynhrNs40u%2BPYBNxc%2BuuHxt6siVevNiZCns9xun6HUZDzrksdgaQbwGxBxa6RulJ%2BSHYuAj0v8%2BWcfivNYfi8YFcsY3ccewO2fKex8bfFxhvELoUx3hSOchEqRvVQhOhWrxpPEPkZKqOcucfDLdU0vCHcFHjBLVTmfyRTcM0lyBzrCRyf2L8%2FNgxY%2BsuXzUuO0SY5Ui41YlRFo%2FB8c0ZOWho2OVI6KvKGr18tAq621rij6HvWkdXxqBcJxUSOdZkOGEwMQxiV2Q%2B3sMJtxUf9RYSqXuhuomslWVK4vYWyGfwNykUGFA%3D%3D)

Comment: Okay. this was helpful, but my idea of using 2 Listmodels was that wanted to store the data from the favorite.qml using settings and JSON, so that when the app closes it should be able to remember those items that was added...with your method how can i achieve that...

Comment: Okay, because you have a persistable JSON requirement, I have refactored out a JSON object that contains the ids of which records were favourited.